# add domain to images source at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dns, httpmodule

I have a number of images on my website (asp.net c# web.application) that are loaded on to my site. I have a specific domain that I use to load images with but I dont have it included in my markup. So at runtime I want to add this domain to the images if they dont already have it added at compile time. Whats the best way of doing this? Is it via a http module? I understand by doing this at runtime will have performance issues so if there are any other ways I am open to suggestions. Most of my images have relative paths. I cant hard code the domain as it changes by environment the application is running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the domain in your web.config's app settings, then at the top of the web form or master page, do:

```
<% string ImagesDomain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImagesDomain"] %>
```

Then in your images, do:

```
<img src="<%=ImagesDomain%>/MyImage.jpg" />
```

Simple enough. Don't worry too much about the performance hit either, it'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that. How about images in stylesheets though?